# Determine difference between COM and .NET DLLs in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to copy and move DLLs from the bin folder to a mapped drive, and I need to register/unregister the DLLs during the process. I've figured out how to do all of this, but there's a catch. The program I'm working on utilizes VB6 COM DLLs and VB.NET .NET DLLs. I understand that COM DLLs use regsvr32.exe, and .NET DLLs use regasm.exe, but I am interested in programmatically calling the correct function, based upon the DLL I am moving. Is there a way to determine what time I am using in Powershell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile( `mydll.dll`)
```

It should raise a BadImageFormatException if it is not a .Net dll.

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx):

"This exception is thrown when the file format of a dynamic link library (.dll file) or an executable (.exe file) does not conform to the format that is expected by the common language runtime. In particular, the exception is thrown under the following conditions:
...

An attempt is made to load an unmanaged dynamic link library or executable (such as a Windows system DLL) as if it were a .NET Framework assembly. The following example illustrates this by using the Assembly.LoadFile method to load Kernel32.dll."